# C++-CLI: UI Control as parameter of external function?

Tags: winforms, function, user-interface, c++-cli

I try to make an interface for the device using WinForms. I have a class which stores all parameters and methods, like below:

```
// device.h:

class Device {

    double parameter_a;
    double parameter_b;

    double setParameterA(double new_value);
    double setParameterB(double new_value);
}
```

Then, I would create an instance and use it's methods to modify parameters by event handling and return either corrected value for UI Control or just 0 if everything is fine.

However, I found that this solution doesn't really make my code shorter, as I still have to modify UI inside my Form document, where all my controls are reachable (if errors / out of range values encountered).

What would I like to do is to somehow pass a kind of pointer to UI Control (like TextBox) to the function and make it like below:

```
void setParameterA(double new_value, *ui_ctrl_pointer* ) {
    // simple value check
    if (new_value > 0) { 
        // numToMStr() - function I have to convert numbers to managed string
        *ui_ctrl_pointer*->Text = numToMStr(new_value); 
        return;
    }
}
```

and modify the control inside the setParameterA() along with input control and setting my device.

**1. Is it possible to make such a thing in C++-cli?**  (if so, what would *ui_ctrl_pointer* look like?)
2. Is this a correct approach or should I stick to the basic solution, which would force me to check for function output to determine what to do with value set by user inside my UI?

Comment: It is not impossible, just a bad idea.  A *Device* should not know anything about a user interface.  Break this kind of coupling with events.  There is a very strong hint that you are falling victim to not designing this top-down and focusing way too much on the device with the UI as an afterthought.  Should setParameterA() not be called because the user typed something in the textbox?  Then there's no need to update the textbox of course.  If the UI displays a value generated by the device then you should never have an "input control", just a label.

Comment: Okay, thank you. This is more complicated, as I have to calculate boundaries for each parameter based on other ones and correct input if needed before I can store new value and use it anywhere else, so setParameterA begins after input check (usually means I need some calculations). Then I guess my only option is to leave the sequence as it is now.